# RGB color list like [255,0,0] to binary like b'\xff\x80\x00' (for blender texture buffer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, integer, type-conversion

sorry if it's a duplicate, I found a lot of pointers but no answer about the following ;

I want to convert that kind of rgb values list :

```
rgb = [ 255,128,0 ]
```

to this binary format :

```
Brgb = b'\xff\x80\x00'
```

this is to feed a GL texture buffer in blender and generate a uniform texture.

so far, I mean since 10mn after 3 hours clicking there and there and testing, I use this lame, but working, code :

```
rgb = [255,128,0]
rgb = "\\x%02X\\x%02X\\x%02X" % (rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2])
brgb = eval("b'%s'"%rgb)

logic.tex.source.load( brgb * (256*256),256,256)
# got this orange texture in my buffer
```

how would you do this properly ?
many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turn the integers into `bytes` *directly*:

```
>>> rgb = [255, 128, 0]
>>> bytes(rgb)
b'\xff\x80\x00'
```

The sequence of integers is directly interpreted as byte values.

Comment: For any future readers using Python 2.x, even though you can't use `bytes` here (because it's a synonym for `str`), you can use `bytearray` just as easily.